# It it possible to get httrack to wait N seconds between each transfer?

Tags: macos, website, download, httrack

I've limited the concurrent connections, and I noticed there is something called --advanced-wait, but the manual does not describe if this might do what I want to do.

The site in question that I want to download have a limit on page loads within a given timeframe, and thus many of the pages downloaded only contains a single error message.

Answer (score 0):

`--advanced-wait` is not what you are looking for: http://forum.httrack.com/readmsg/14145/14143/index.html?q=httrack+advanced-wait

Also I did not find option which can set how much time to wait between connections.